# Google Analytics - track form submission

Tags: google-analytics

I know this is possible to track how many people have actually clicked on the submit button of  form, but my form has a validation, if someones click on submit without entering a value, GA will count this, but this is not a real submission.

How do i track how many people have actually submitted the form using GA?

please let me know

thanks

Comment: Is the post request processed on the same page?

Comment: @Victor yes,user will remain on the same page after submitting the form, and if he does not enter a value in a field, he will get an error message.

Comment: if you are showing user any response after successful submission (I mean after all validations) - you can insert code of event there

Answer (score 0):

You can output the GA code on success of your post request. A basic in page php example would be something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    echo "<script>_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Contact', 'Inquiry', 'Inquiry Form', 0, false]);<script>";
}
```

You can also use the `onSubmit` function. A client side solution would be this:

```
<form id="form-name" name="form-name" action="submission-url-goes-here" method="post" 
 onSubmit="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'FormName', 'FormSubmit', 'FormSubmissionCompleted']);">
```

Comment: @Victor onsubmit would only count the real submission? not if you just click on the submit button?

Comment: Correct, only when the form successfully submits